# Unified or separated registration for sites with two clear types of users

Tags: registration

My company has two clear types of users, just like uber has drivers and passengers or Airbnb has hosts and guest.

What approach would you recommend for registration process and forms, unified experience with differentiation happening later in the process or totally different registration process starting with two clear separated type of users?

Just like with Uber or Airbnb an user can have both roles if he wants.

Comment: Please edit your question to identify your two types of users. Dealing with hypotheticals isn't likely to help you much.

Comment: I second @TimGrant's comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to make a clear CTA distinction before registration even starts. So users can instantly understand what are the 2 types of users, which one they belong to and have an idea of how Type A and Type B interplay.

During the registration, depending on how different your Type A and Type B are, you can either make the forms similar or customized to each. It really depends on the information you want to collect and how involved the registration process is (e.g. common users vs users needing to submit proofs of certifications, documents, etc for vetting).

Maybe your Type A only has 1 page with 3 fields, and your Type B is multi-step process because of business reasons and amount of data collection requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

- **User can be of typeA and typeB**: In this case both an specific registration to the first type the user is going to be and a common registration where changes can be made later on, could work. In the examples you propose, lets take Airbnb, a user can be a host and a guest (not at the same time, of course).
- **User can only be of one type**: If a user can't be of both typeA and typeB it makes sense to have a different registration process as the accounts are different.